# Bitcasting an ObjC method with no arguments

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

We have a method in objective-c that we would like to bitcast to swift, we have completed the task for most of the methods, but are stuck on how to handle voids. The swift code is below:

```
extension PMKPromise {
    private func objCBlockFromPromiseClosure(closure: (AnyObject) -> (PMKPromise?)) -> AnyObject {
        return unsafeBitCast(closure as @convention(block) (AnyObject) -> (PMKPromise?), AnyObject.self)
    }

    func swiftThen(closure: (AnyObject) -> (PMKPromise?)) -> PMKPromise {
        return self.then()(objCBlockFromPromiseClosure(closure))
    }

    func swiftCatch(closure: (AnyObject) -> (PMKPromise?)) -> PMKPromise {
        return self.catchOn()(dispatch_get_main_queue(), objCBlockFromPromiseClosure(closure))
    }
}
```

The corresponding Objective-C code for the above is here:

```
- (PMKPromise *(^)(id))then;
- (PMKPromise *(^)(dispatch_queue_t, id))catchOn;
```

And the method we need help with is here:

```
- (PMKPromise *(^)(void(^)(void)))finally;
```

Creating a new swiftFinally(closure) function is the goal, but we are unsure of the type to use for closure or the bitcast.

Thank you.

Comment: `- (PMKPromise *(^)(void(^)(void)))finally;` bridges to Swift as `func finally() -> (((() -> Void)!) -> PMKPromise!)!`.  Are you looking for just the interface or the entire function?

Comment: I'm actually looking to do something like: `func swiftThen(closure: (AnyObject) -> (PMKPromise?)) -> PMKPromise` the problem with what you posted above is that its lacking the closure param. Thanks for helping.